Tensorflow 2.17 - Saving custom model does not work for me
(tensorflow 2.17, Windows 10)
I can't save and restore a custom model using subclassing method.
Please find below the code to reproduce the problem :
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x = np.random.random((1000, 32))
y = np.random.random((1000, 1))

@tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable()
class MModel(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
        self.dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.dense1(inputs)
        return self.dense2(x)

model = MModel()

model.compile( optimizer="adam",  loss="mse",  metrics=["mae"])
model.fit( x, y, epochs=5)

model.save("save1.keras")
model_ = tf.keras.models.load_model("save1.keras")

print()
print(f"{model.evaluate(x, y,verbose=0)  = }")
print(f"{model_.evaluate(x, y,verbose=0) = }")

for m, m_ in zip(model.weights, model_.weights):
    np.testing.assert_allclose(m.numpy(), m_.numpy())

Please note that the init() has no parameters, hence no need to override get_config().
The error message :
TypeError: <class '__main__.MModel'> could not be deserialized properly. Please ensure that components that are Python object instances (layers, models, etc.) returned by `get_config()` are explicitly deserialized in the model's `from_config()` method.

config={'module': None, 'class_name': 'MModel', 'config': {'trainable': True, 'dtype': {'module': 'keras', 'class_name': 'DTypePolicy', 'config': {'name': 'float32'}, 'registered_name': None}}, 'registered_name': 'Custom>MModel', 'build_config': {'input_shape': [None, 32]}, 'compile_config': {'optimizer': {'module': 'keras.optimizers', 'class_name': 'Adam', 'config': {'name': 'adam', 'learning_rate': 0.0010000000474974513, 'weight_decay': None, 'clipnorm': None, 'global_clipnorm': None, 'clipvalue': None, 'use_ema': False, 'ema_momentum': 0.99, 'ema_overwrite_frequency': None, 'loss_scale_factor': None, 'gradient_accumulation_steps': None, 'beta_1': 0.9, 'beta_2': 0.999, 'epsilon': 1e-07, 'amsgrad': False}, 'registered_name': None}, 'loss': 'mse', 'loss_weights': None, 'metrics': ['mae'], 'weighted_metrics': None, 'run_eagerly': False, 'steps_per_execution': 1, 'jit_compile': False}}.

Exception encountered: Unable to revive model from config. When overriding the `get_config()` method, make sure that the returned config contains all items used as arguments in the  constructor to <class '__main__.MModel'>, which is the default behavior. You can override this default behavior by defining a `from_config(cls, config)` class method to specify how to create an instance of MModel from its config.

Received config={'trainable': True, 'dtype': {'module': 'keras', 'class_name': 'DTypePolicy', 'config': {'name': 'float32'}, 'registered_name': None}}

Error encountered during deserialization: MModel.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'trainable'


In init(), I forgot to pass the keyword arguments to the superclass.
This code is working now :
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x = np.random.random((1000, 32))
y = np.random.random((1000, 1))

@tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable()
class MModel(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
        self.dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.dense1(inputs)
        return self.dense2(x)

model = MModel()

model.compile( optimizer="adam",  loss="mse",  metrics=["mae"])
model.fit( x, y, epochs=5)

model.save("save1.keras")
model_ = tf.keras.models.load_model("save1.keras")

print()
print(f"{model.evaluate(x, y,verbose=0)  = }")
print(f"{model_.evaluate(x, y,verbose=0) = }")

for m, m_ in zip(model.weights, model_.weights):
    np.testing.assert_allclose(m.numpy(), m_.numpy())

